# pandas month between previous record same customer

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a list of customers ID and that date of purchase
when a customer is repeated I need a new column with the number of days between the   purchase date and the previous record purchase rate

```
Cust Data        Days
123  2018-08-01
123  2018-09-01   31
124  2018-05-05
125  2017-01-25
125  2017-02-12   18
125  2017-06-14  122
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: df.groupby('Cust').Data.diff()

Comment: @F.Valle, if the solution solved your issue, please don't forget to mark it with a green tick. This helps the community know which issues are solved

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert `'Data'` to datetime format.

```
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'])
```

And then, get the difference between days:

```
df[['Cust','Data']].groupby(['Cust']).diff()

      Data
0      NaT
1  31 days
2      NaT
3      NaT
4  18 days
5 122 days
```

To remove NaT (NaN of datetime) you can either drop them (`df.dropna()`) or fill them (`df.fillna(0)`).